# Why can't I change the local bind address of my SSH tunnel?

Tags: python, docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to create an SSH tunnel to a remote database as part of a Python script running in a Docker container. Specifically, I am using the [sshtunnel](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package.

When I set the local bind address to (localhost, 5432), then everything works perfectly. However, I am trying to create multiple SSH connections to the same database so that multiple queries can run simultaneously. When I try to create multiple connections on the same local port (5432), then the connection fails. When I change the local bind address to 8080, or 5431, or another other port, then sshtunnel returns an error: `Problem setting SSH Forwarder up: Couldn't open tunnel localhost:8080 <> localhost:5432 might be in use or destination not reachable`.

Do I need to do something in my Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml in order to make another port usable as the local bind address? Here is the SSH connection code I am using:

```
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
       ('somehost.org', 33696),
       ssh_username=secrets.DB_USERNAME,
       ssh_pkey=secrets.ssh_private_key,
       remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432),
       local_bind_address=('localhost', 5432), #changing to 5431, 8080, etc causes error 
   ):
       # run a query here
```

Comment: Can you make multiple connections over the same ssh tunnel connection?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze for the question. My original code did just that, but additional database connections using the same SSH tunnel were intermittently being closed by the database, and the owners of the DB told me to implement this approach instead. Is that the more typical approach?